# Selecting lowest price for multiple products

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

Hy all,

For a project i need an overview of all products to find the supplier with the lowest price. So for every product there must be 1 outcome with a price and supplier

If have tried like a hundred query but i just can't find the right one.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [picture_name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[supplier](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[supplier_overview_product](
 [supplier] [int] NOT NULL,
 [product] [int] NOT NULL,
 [price] [real] NOT NULL)
```

Product is FK to product
Supplier is FK to supplier

This is what i have:

```
SELECT s.name, MIN(sop.price)
FROM dbo.supplier_overview_product AS sop
JOIN dbo.product AS p
ON sop.product = p.id
JOIN dbo.supplier AS s
ON s.id  = sop.supplier
GROUP BY s.name
```

But there is no supplier. And i want to know who that is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Analytic functions. Partition by supplier and find Min(price) within the partition - SELECT Min(price) OVER (PARTITION BY supplier ORDER BY something) as min_price... Use RANK(), ROW_NUMBER() etc... Some Oracle example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567911/sql-rank-based-on-date/14569238#14569238

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm understanding your question to mean you want the supplier with the lowest price for each product.

The [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) orders the suppliers by price for each product, and the main query uses that ordering to only retrieve the supplier with the lowest price.

**NOTE**: Because I'm using `RANK`, if multiple suppliers happen to have the same lowest price, they will all be returned.  If this is incorrect, change `RANK` to `ROW_NUMBER`

```
;WITH SuppliersByPrice AS (
    SELECT product, supplier, price,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY price) as ord
    FROM supplier_overview_product
)
SELECT SBP.product, SBP.price, S.name
FROM SuppliersByPrice SBP
    INNER JOIN Supplier S ON S.id = SBP.supplier
WHERE SBP.ord = 1
```

Comment: i understand it now. U build a temporary column with the data from Supplier_overview_product and add an rank for each product by rank! And that u select where the rank is 1(lowest). Many thanks!!!